# Is this a valid method to solve this PDE

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I have obtained the correct solution to this PDE but my method required me to treat the partial dv/dsigma as if it were a fraction which im fairly sure is invalid. Could someone confirm this for me and guide me towards a correct method?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can [format maths here using MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).